# jQuery show-hide find next element far and near

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, show-hide

This show-hide function attempts to do so anonymously, without the need to maintain unique IDs for the target divs.

I am having trouble understanding why my selector for the `var div` does not work in example #4, and how I may be able to get it working for all examples shown.

```js
$('.expander').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = $(this).nextAll('div.content').first();
    if (div)
    {
        if (div.css('display') == "none")
        {
            div.show();
            $(this).removeClass("closed");
            $(this).addClass("open");
        }
        else
        {
            div.hide();
            $(this).removeClass("open");
            $(this).addClass("closed");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#" class="expander open">example 1</a><br />
    <div class="content open">shown content</div>
    <a href="#" class="expander closed">example 2</a><br />
    <div class="content closed">hidden content</div>
    <a href="#" class="expander closed">example 3</a><br />
    <!-- comments -->
    <span>other content</span>
    <div class="content closed">hidden content</div>
    <p>
        <span>
            <a href="#" class="expander closed">example 4</a>
        </span>
    </p>
    <div class="content closed">content</div>
</div>
```

The first three examples work fine.  But when I deployed this code, I found there were variations in how the anchor may be coded.  I am looking for a solution that works regardless of how the anchor is encapsulated.

The bottom line is I want to select the next div.content to the anchor, regardless if it is next, or if jQuery must walk up the DOM tree a little to find it.

I have a working model of this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HdjfY/17/).

Comment: I wish I knew what was wrong with the syntax coloring of the HTML in my post.

Comment: ahhh.  I figured out the syntax coloring in the post. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you anchor is `nested inside a span` which again nested inside `a ptag`

And this does not make sense in case of example# 4
`var div = $(this).nextAll('div.content').first();`

For **example#4** you need this selector

```
var div = $(this).closest('p').nextAll('div.content').first();
```

Comment: I am using this, site wide, with variations in how the anchor tag is encoded.  Your example may work, but it is specific to the `P` tag.  I am hoping there is a way to code this so it works for all, not just this special case... because, frankly there are other special cases, too.  example, anchor tag and div within an unordered list, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working walking up the parent tree until I see the next target div.

```
var div = $(this).nextAll('div.content').first();
if (div.length == 0)
{
    div = $(this).parentsUntil('body').nextAll('div.content').first();
}
```

I don't really like the conditional, but unless I find something more elegant, I'll stick with this.